# Eclipse Table widget with SWT.CHECK is fireing two events when a TableItem is selected

Tags: java, events, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm making an Eclipse (3.6.2) CDT (7.0.2) Plugin which uses my own wizard page (extending MBSCustomPage). This wizard page shows a Table filled with some TableItems that can be checked or unchecked by clicking on them (as usual). **The problem is that I'm always receiving two events when a TableItem checkbox is cheked (or unchecked)!**. In the first event received, I have a (SelectedEvent)e.detail == SWT.CHECK, even if the TableItem was checked first, and in the second event, the (SelectedEvent)e.detail == 0!. So I have no way to know if the TableItem is really checked or not.
This is my code (somewhat):

```
final Table table = new Table( composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.CHECK );
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
table.setLinesVisible(false);

(...)

table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        CheckThatOnlyOneItemCanBeCheckedAtTime(e.item);
        //If someone check on me, save the item data value in a "container"
        if( e.detail == SWT.CHECK ) {
            MBSCustomPageManager.addPageProperty(PAGE_ID, "SDK_Path", ((ISdk)((TableItem)e.item).getData()).getPath() );
        } else { //Otherwise, unset the saved value
            MBSCustomPageManager.addPageProperty(PAGE_ID, "SDK_Path", "" );
        }
    }
});
```

Why is widgetSelected() being called two times when I click on the checkbox of a TableItem?
I tested that the events are fired even if there is no code inside the widgetSelected() method.
I didn't find anything Googling around or looking in Eclipse Bugzilla database... really strange to me, but I'm not an experienced Eclipse plugin coder (not even Java) :)

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
table.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
    String string = arg0.detail == SWT.CHECK ? "Checked" : "Selected";
    if (arg0.detail == SWT.CHECK) {
      System.out.println(arg0.item + " " + string+ ":" + 
                         ((Table)arg0.widget).getSelection()[0].getChecked());
     }                         
     else {
       System.out.println(arg0.item + " " + string);
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: Use ((TableItem)arg0.item).getChecked() instead.  The code above may not resolve to the item being checked since it looks for the first selected item (which may or may not be the item being checked).  It will give a Null pointer exception (NPE) is no table items are selected (and no items need to be selected in order to check/uncheck items).